# How can I train a model in statsmodels?

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels

This is a pretty straightforward question and I know some will be inclined to give a -1, but please let me explain better.

Most of statsmodels tutorials in the internet (such as [this](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/gettingstarted.html), [this](https://www.learndatasci.com/tutorials/predicting-housing-prices-linear-regression-using-python-pandas-statsmodels/) and [this](https://medium.com/evidentebm/linear-regression-using-statsmodels-d0db5fef16bb)) usually create a Linear Regression without splitting the dataset into train and test. They create a linear regression using this sintax:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
sm.ols('y~x1+x2+x3', data=df).fit()
```

There is no need to say how dangerous is to build a model without a test dataset.

My question here is how can I create a linear regression with statsmodels, using train and test split?

After searching a lot, I found this approach:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
features, target, train_size=0.8, random_state=42
)

import statsmodels.api as sm

smfOLS = smf.OLS(X_train, y_train).fit()
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'statsmodels.formula.api' has no attribute 'OLS'
```

I know I should provide a dataset, but unfortunately, I'm working with confidential data. But any dataset you have should be enough to understand the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
features, target, train_size=0.8, random_state=42
)

import statsmodels.api as sm


smfOLS = sm.OLS(y_train, X_train).fit()
```

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake. Actually, the answer didn't work. I got this error message: ValueError: shapes (1476,7) and (1476,7) not aligned: 7 (dim 1) != 1476 (dim 0)

Comment: well, by changing X_train and y_train positions the answer works.

Comment: This error is not elated to your question, i answered your question related to your attribute error, you were loading the wrong module. This time it is related to your data, please post another question and accept my answer.

Comment: actually, the answer is still wrong because X_train and y_train are not in the correct position. statsmodels always puts y_train first. Please edit the answer to sm.OLS(y_train, X_train),fit(). I already marked as correct anyway. Many thanks XD